# Subsetting multiple variables by rank within data-frame

Tags: rstudio

Hopefully the below makes sense.

I have a data set a large number of variables (row). Within each variable are sections that are scored 1-15. I need to subset the dataframe based on the three highest scoring sections for each variable. Each section has additional data associated with it that would be needed, but is not required as part of the selection.

Having trouble with this. Any help is appreciated.

Dummy layout below

Variable    Aux_score
1   1
1   6
1   3
1   8
1   10
2   3
2   2
2   12
2   10
2   11
3   7
3   2
3   9
3   8
3   12

Comment: What you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with base r:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Variable), function(df) df[ tail(order(df$Aux_score), 3), ]))
```

Or like this with tidyverse:

```
df %>% group_by(Variable) %>% top_n(3, Aux_score) %>% ungroup()
```